# Sencha Touch/ Cordova - Android - building APK with Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, sencha-touch-2, apk

our way for building a android apk is the following:

We've got mainly two directories

- The sencha touch project directory
- A directory for the native android stuff, which contains an android project -> created with eclipse

If we made some changes in the sencha touch stuff we build a sencha touch package using

```
sencha app build package
```

After this we copy the package into the native\android\assets\www directory and do some other stuff like translating, etc. (all this steps will be done by executing a script)..

Then I open Android Studio and import the project with "import project from existing source code" and can compile an apk.

I'm using AndroidStudio 0.1.9, there everything is working fine, my teammates using much newer versions of android studio and there is the problem, that they can't just import our project with "import project from existing source code". In their versions they just can import a "gradle project".

So what's the best way now for generating an android apk of our app?

- My teammates downgrade to my AndroidStudio version?
- We convert our project to a gradle project?
- We setup a new gradle project and move this in our native/android directory
- Something completly else?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha build generates only some static stuff like html/js/css/resources. Can't you just copy paste the generated folder to your project?

If you use android studio only for create the native application ( .apk file ) you could try the built in support for phonegap inside sencha cmd.
Heres the tutorial:

```
sencha phonegap init
```

It enables phonegap on your project.
Edit phonegap.local.properties file (root folder of your project) -> phonegap.platform=android and run:

```
sencha app build native or sencha app build -run native
```